# CSS position of button shifted when in safari but works fine in chrome

Tags: html, css

The position of the "go" button sits properly when viewed in chrome, but when you view it in safari, the position is slightly off. Any recommendations on how to fix it?

Chrome screenshot
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Safari screenshot
[image: safari]

HTML code for button

```
       <form action="{{url_for('search')}}" method="post">
        <!--id="" will be useful for backend and css-->
        <!--only inputs with name="" will be submitted-->
        <input required name="movie_title" id="movie_title" type="text" placeholder="  Search movie...">
        <button type="submit" class = "go">GO</button>
       </form>
```

CSS for button

```
  .go {
        background-color: #2768B5;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 7px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Could you make a short snippet which shows the problem? Get rid of the bits that aren't relevant to the problem but show any bits that are - such as the CSS related to the input element.

Comment: @Person thats not enough css to determine whats going on. You need to provide more. Like your form and input css too.